STM32 internal Flash Status register reset value is not 0x0000 0000
I am trying to write to the internal Flash of STM32L476. Using STM32CubeIde, when I run the debugger, I observed that FLASH->SR = 0xC0.
I am using this code to write to the Flash
    if(FLASH->CR & FLASH_CR_LOCK)
    {
    FLASH->KEYR = FLASH_KEY1;
    FLASH->KEYR = FLASH_KEY2;
    }

    if(!(FLASH->CR & FLASH_CR_LOCK))
    {
        if(!(FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY))
        {
            FLASH->SR |=  (FLASH_FLAG_OPERR   | FLASH_FLAG_PROGERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR | \
                    FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR  | FLASH_FLAG_SIZERR  | FLASH_FLAG_PGSERR | \
                    FLASH_FLAG_MISERR  | FLASH_FLAG_FASTERR | FLASH_FLAG_RDERR  | \
                    FLASH_FLAG_OPTVERR);
            FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_BKER;
            FLASH->CR &= ~FLASH_CR_PNB_Msk;
            FLASH->CR |= (511 & 0xFF) << FLASH_CR_PNB_Pos;
            FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_PER;
            FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_STRT;
            while(FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY)
                ;
            FLASH->CR &= ~(FLASH_CR_PER | FLASH_CR_PNB);
        }

        if(!(FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY))
        {
            FLASH->SR |=  (FLASH_FLAG_OPERR   | FLASH_FLAG_PROGERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR | \
                    FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR  | FLASH_FLAG_SIZERR  | FLASH_FLAG_PGSERR | \
                    FLASH_FLAG_MISERR  | FLASH_FLAG_FASTERR | FLASH_FLAG_RDERR  | \
                    FLASH_FLAG_OPTVERR);
            FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_PG;
            /* Program first word */
            *(__IO uint32_t*)(0x080FF800) = (uint32_t)0x01020304;

            /* Barrier to ensure programming is performed in 2 steps, in right order
                (independently of compiler optimization behavior) */
            __ISB();
            /* Program second word */
            *(__IO uint32_t*)(0x080FF800 + 4U) = (uint32_t)0x05060708;
            while(FLASH->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY)
                ;


            FLASH->SR |= FLASH_SR_EOP;
            FLASH->CR &= ~FLASH_CR_PG;
        }
    }
    FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_LOCK;

I can see the contents of the Flash memory are changing.

after executing the code, the first time I pause the code it shows the content in red with a blue triangle beside the values, at this time the FLASH-SR = 0x00. When latter I pause the code again, I can see FLASH-SR = 0xC0 and the contents of the memory are displayed in black.
According to the reference manual, the status register should be FLASH-SR = 0x00.
What is the explanation for this behavior? What am I doing wrong that is causing such behavior?
Edit 06-06-2024:
I am adding screen shots to show how persistent this issue. I created a new project, without even initializing most of the peripherals.
1- Just entered the code, no command executed yet

2- executed FLASH->SR |= FLASH_FLAG_SR_ERRORS;

3- execute HAL_Init();

4- executed FLASH->SR |= FLASH_FLAG_SR_ERRORS;

5- execute SystemClock_Config();

6- executed FLASH->SR |= FLASH_FLAG_SR_ERRORS;

7- execute HAL_FLASH_Unlock();

8- execute FLASH->SR |= FLASH_FLAG_SR_ERRORS;

9- execute MX_GPIO_Init();

You can see FLASH->SR = 0xC0 keep coming after each time I clear it.
There is no interrupts or any other code running in the background.
-Thanks

So, did you check the meaning of the flags?

Bit 6 error flag:  SIZERR: Size error.
Set by hardware when the size of the access is a byte or half-word during a
program or a fast program sequence. Only double word programming is allowed.
Try writing a 64-bit value rather than 32-bit value. EDIT: if you find it weird that it mentions byte, half word and double word, but doesn't mention a single word, I find it weird too. It seems however to require a strictly double word access for writes.

Thanks for the reply, I understand the error meaning. what is puzzling me is, after clearing it, then unlocking the FLASH, I get the same error. I didn't write to it at all.

What I wanted to say is, this error is persistent and sticky.

"Displayed in black" part means it didn't change since the last breakpoint. It color-highlights what changed. And if it was 0x00 and became 0xC0, then there was another write attempt. "at this time the FLASH-SR = 0x00". The write was successful. After that, another write (probably of bug nature) occurred.

@Ilya I edited and added more information to the original post

Thanks for that little test project demonstration. A really good idea. It really is strange. I even checked errata sheet, there are a couple Flash things, but nothing seems to be related to this. The fact that Flash error flags are set even before the first line of main(), is really strange. I suspect it's some unreported silicon bug, otherwise why would it have error flags even before it does anything in main. Out of curiosity, try __disable_irq(); first in test program main(). Found a random post that had a strangle flash problem go away with it. Other than that, out of ideas atm.

@Ilya Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it and it did not work.

How about this: mass erase the flash. Completely. Then let the MCU run. Obviously, it should hardfault immediately. Connect debugger with STM32CubeProgrammer, halt the CPU and inspect Flash SR register. I'm curious whether Flash error flags are set before startup.
